# apt update giving debian error returned a non-zero code: 100, Code: 100

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I am trying to run a `Dockerfile` using a `docker-compose.yml`. When I run the command `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up` I get the following error:

```
 ⠿ stm-api Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.4s
Sending build context to Docker daemon    507kB
Step 1/21 : FROM python:3.9-slim
 ---> aac9cadfe26d
Step 2/21 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> afa0117f4e20
Step 3/21 : RUN apt update
 ---> Running in ad4b6176867e

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 142.182.19.19 80]
Err:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 142.182.19.19 80]
Err:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 142.182.19.19 80]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
1 error occurred:
        * Status: The command '/bin/sh -c apt update' returned a non-zero code: 100, Code: 100
```

I added the following in the `etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

It didn't seem to resolve the error.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1074688/security-debian-org-does-not-have-a-release-file-on-with-debian-docker-images